# How to dynamically render images on click from a table column reference after table is sorted

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get the images associated with rows of data to show on a button click after they've been filtered. This could be in an info box or just on their own below the table.

I also tried to have the images just show in the table, but they're too small to be useful, so it would be better if they could be separate from the table so I can specify the size.

I have a .csv file with the following kind of info and was trying images stored locally or on the web (hence the two image columns).

.csv example
ID,Continuous,Broken,PB,Lips L,Lips R,Sig. dor. or ped. scar,Image (in www folder),ImageTest

1820,Y,N,2,Y,Y,Y,1820CelloHeadshot.jpg,http://rwcatalog.neaq.org/ImageViewer.aspx?ImageId=826703

This is what I have so far for coding that works for the table and sorting:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# default global search value
if (!exists("default_search")) default_search <- ""

# default column search values
if (!exists("default_search_columns")) default_search_columns <- NULL

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel(title = h1("Upload file and select columns", align = "center")),

 # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Select a file ----
  fileInput("uploaded_file", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),

  # Horizontal line ----
  tags$hr(),

  # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

  # Input: Select separator ----
  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Semicolon = ";",
                           Comma = ",",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ","),


  # Horizontal line ----
  tags$hr(),

  # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
  radioButtons("disp", "Display",
               choices = c(All = "all",
                           Head = "head"),
               selected = "all"),

  # Select variables to display ----
  uiOutput("checkbox")

),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(
    id = "dataset",
    tabPanel("FILE", DT::dataTableOutput("rendered_file"))
  )
)

 )
  )

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

 # Read file ----
 df <- reactive({
 req(input$uploaded_file)
 read.csv(input$uploaded_file$datapath,
         header = input$header,
         sep = input$sep)  

  })

  # Dynamically generate UI input when data is uploaded ----
  output$checkbox <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select_var", 
                   label = "Select variables", 
                   choices = names(df()))
  })

 # Select columns to print ----
  df_sel <- reactive({
  req(input$select_var)
  df_sel <- df() %>% select(input$select_var)
   })

  # Print data table ----  
  output$rendered_file <- DT::renderDataTable(

class = "display nowrap compact",
filter = "top",

{
if(input$disp == "head") {
  head(df_sel())
}
else {
  df_sel()
}
  })

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This part works fine, I'm just not sure about how to code for a button that would specify that I only want to save and render the images from the filtered results. Any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  image = c("Barth sextic", "Mandelbulb", "Space egg"),
  file = c("BarthSextic.png", "Mandelbulb.png", "SpaceEgg.png")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  uiOutput("images")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, filter = "top")
  })

  df <- reactive({
    dat[input[["table_rows_current"]], ]
  })

  output[["images"]] <- renderUI({
    imgs <- lapply(df()$file, function(file){
      tags$div(
        tags$img(src= file, width="100%"),
        style = "width: 400px;"
      )
    })
    do.call(tagList, imgs)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

With a slideshow:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(slickR)

dat <- data.frame(
  image = c("Barth sextic", "Mandelbulb", "Space egg"),
  file = c("BarthSextic.png", "Mandelbulb.png", "SpaceEgg.png")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  div(
    slickROutput("images"),
    style = "width: 75%; margin: auto;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, filter = "top")
  })

  df <- reactive({
    req(input[["table_rows_current"]])
    dat[input[["table_rows_current"]], ]
  })

  output[["images"]] <- renderSlickR({
    slickR(paste0("www/", df()$file))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was wanting to do! I just haven't figured out how to integrate it with the uploading a .csv file bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was what I was thinking! I can't seem to get it to display properly when I add in the uploading of the .csv though. I took out some of the other stuff in the original sidebar to figure out where the problem was. And I renamed the image column to "whaleimage".

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

# App title ----
titlePanel(title = h1("Upload file and select columns", align = "center")),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Select a file ----
  fileInput("whaleid", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),

  # Horizontal line ----
  tags$hr(),


  # Select variables to display ----
  DTOutput("table"),
  uiOutput("images")

),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(
  tableOutput("table"),
imageOutput("images"))
))

server <- function(input, output){

output$table <- renderDT({
datatable(whaleid, filter = "top")
})

df <- reactive({
whaleid[input$table_rows_current, ]
})

output$images <- renderUI({
imgs <- lapply(df()$whaleimage, function(whaleimage){
  tags$div(
    tags$img(src= whaleimage, width="100%"),
    style = "width: 400px;"
  )
})
do.call(tagList, imgs)
})

}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reworked it now and can get the images to display, but can't figure out where to specify the "table_rows_current" command in order to only get the filtered images to show. Any ideas?

```
 library(shiny)     #  Shiny web app
 library(DT)        #  for data tables

 # ui object
 ui <- fluidPage(  

 titlePanel("Upload file"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  # Input: Select a file ----
  fileInput("uploaded_file", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),

  # Horizontal line ----
  tags$hr(),

  # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

  # Input: Select separator ----
  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Semicolon = ";",
                           Comma = ",",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ",")

),
mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(
    id = "dataset",
    tabPanel("FILE", DT::dataTableOutput("rendered_file"), htmlOutput("headshots")))
)
)
)  




# server()
server <- function(input, output){ 

# Read file ----
df <- reactive({
req(input$uploaded_file)
read.csv(input$uploaded_file$datapath,
         header = input$header,
         sep = input$sep)

##column selection for image display

df_sel <- reactive({
df[input$table_rows_current,]
})

})

# Print data table ----  
output$rendered_file <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(df(), class = "display nowrap 
compact", filter = "top")})

# Print images of selection ----
output$headshots <- renderUI({
imgs <-lapply(df_sel()$whaleimage, function(file){ 
  tags$div(
  tags$img(src= file, width="100%"),
  style = "width: 400px;"
)
})
do.call(tagList, imgs)
})
}



 # run the app
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```